# Add set to set and make nested sets

Tags: python, set, nested

In Python I want to make sets consisting of sets, so I get a set of sets (nested sets).

Example:

```
{{1,2}, {2,3}, {4,5}}
```

However when I try the following:

```
s = set()
s.add(set((1,2)))
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    s.add(set((1,2)))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Can anyone tell me where my mistake is and how I achieve my goal please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is that sets can only contain [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects, and a `set` is not hashable.

You should use the [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) type, which *is* hashable, for the elements of the outer set.

```
In [3]: s = set([frozenset([1,2]), frozenset([3,4])])

In [4]: s
Out[4]: {frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({3, 4})}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your quick response :)

Okey, now I understand it. However I get involved with a further issue:

`set()` and `frozenset()` both create a (frozen)set with multiple elements if you give them a string parameter, like this:

`>>> set('ab')
{'a', 'b'}`

`>>> frozenset('ab')
frozenset({'a', 'b'})`

Why they split the string in to separate elements?
I wanted to get `{'ab'}` resp. `frozenset({'ab'})`

Could you please help me once again?

Comment: @John - `frozenset` is iterating over the string and collecting its characters into a new frozenset.  You would need to do `frozenset(['ab'])` to keep the string intact.

Comment: @iCodez - thank you once again for your help - now it works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a set of sets because sets are unhashable objects; they can be mutated by adding or removing items from them.

You will need to use a set of [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) instead:

```
s = set()
s.add(frozenset((1,2)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(frozenset((1,2)))
>>> s.add(frozenset((2,3)))
>>> s.add(frozenset((4,5)))
>>> s
{frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({4, 5})}
>>>
```

Frozensets are like normal sets in every respect except that they cannot be mutated.  This feature makes them [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) and allows you to use them as items of a set or keys of a dictionary.